# drag and drop on a Rubyscript: displaying raise errormessage?

Tags: ruby, windows, drag-and-drop, console

I have a script which I start by a drag and drop of a file from Explorer onto a link on the Windows Desktop to my script, so the filename becomes the parameter of my script. This is handy for users who don't know how to start my script with a valid parameter. This part works perfectly.

But when I raise an error in the script, the errormessage is displayed but the console window closes without giving the user the time to read the message.
Putting a `gets` or a `sleep` at the end of the script or after the `raise` doesn't help.

How do I fix that please ?

```
if ARGV[0] 
  filename = ARGV[0]
else
  raise "No filename given"
end
#some other code with wrong data
error = true
if error   
  raise "An error has occured, wrong data"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this around your entire program:

```
begin
  all your code...
rescue
  puts $!
  system('pause')
end
```

Comment: as i indicated in my question a gets isn't waited for, i tried but the window closes

Comment: @peter: Did you wrap it in the `begin`...`rescue`...`end`? And try replacing `gets` with `system('pause')`.

Comment: yep i did, just tested the system('pause') at home and that works, thanks